# mvc4 dll dependencies issue C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, apache-kafka

I am developing mvc web app. In this app I am integrating `kafka` so I have downloaded the source code from https://github.com/ExactTargetDev/kafka-net.

I added `Kafka.Client dll` to my mvc4 web app. When I create a `producer` it is giving me an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its
>   dependencies.  The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference.  (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)":"log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821

I searched on this error and update my web.config file

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="1b44e1d426115821" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.2.10.0-1.2.15.0" newVersion="1.2.15.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But still getting an error. After updating `web.config` I am getting following error.

Here is full exception that I am getting

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Kafka.Client.Producers.ProducerPool' threw an exception. ---> 
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net,
>   Version=1.2.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or
>   one of its dependencies.  The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException:  Could not load file or
>   assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies.  The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

In my mvc project I am using `log4net-1.2.15` and in **Kafka-Client project** it is `log4net-1.2.10`

I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Can someone help me solve this?

Comment: What version of visual studio and what version of nuget are you using?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012 and nuget  2.8.50926.602

Comment: Do you physically have the log4net dll?

Comment: @misha130 Yes I have. In my mvc project I have `log4net-1.2.15` version file and in Kafka-client there is `log4net-1.2.10`

Comment: Does it have to be that implementation of Kafka? There is this one https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net which has a nuget package and it doesn't look like it requires any dependencies

Comment: what do you mean by "Does it have to be that implementation of Kafka"?